# working with wp_nav_menu on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm having an issue working with wp_nav_menu, I'm trying to create my own Theme for WP, now i've putted that code into my functions.php file,

```
function register_my_menu() {
  register_nav_menu('header-menu',__( 'Header Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );
```

as the guide said, and now when I'm trying to combine it into my design, the paramters I pass in the wp_nav_menu function doesn't really do anything, and I dont really understand why, I tried to play with it but it doesnt seem like something gets changed.
`

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="danny" class="danny">%3$s</ul>','theme_location' => 'header-menu' ) );
```

`
it doesnt metter what I do, what I add as a paramter the output stays as it is, anyone has anyidea? am I missing something?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not instead of registering your menu, you just use 'menu' parameter like this:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'items_wrap'      => '<ul class="%2$s danny" id="danny">%3$s</ul>','menu' => 'header-menu' ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Take another peek at the Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Instead of passing that markup try the parameters for menu_class and menu_id. for example:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu', 'menu_class' => 'danny', 'menu_id' => 'danny' ) ); ?>
```

Comment: Im trying to get parameters into the UL tag, there is a way to add an ID for the UL ?
to make it like
`<ul id="nav">`
and to the Li to make it like,
`<li class="ldrop">` ???

thanks!

Comment: Just curious why you need it so specific instead of using the classes it's spitting out now.